# UEFI system settings are not accessible by keypress

Tags: mount, grub, uefi, bootloader, dualboot

After configuring dual-boot with 2 nvme-ssds it is impossible for me to reach the uefi system settings.

I have a manjaro drive with the grub bootloader, which is configured to also boot windows. However windows also has it’s own bootloader, which starts by default.

if I try to **boot** into **uefi system settings** neither pressing the **dedicated f2 key** nor acess **via grub** nor using **windows advanced startup** work.

The 2 software options end up restarting my pc into the manufacturer splash screen, whereafter the pc is unresponsive and I have to force shutdown by long pressing the powerkey.

In linux shell it tells me the uefi system settings are **unmounted**. Is that a potential problem, if so how do i remedy that.